# Can a knot diagram be recovered from this data?

Tags: knot-theory

Given a knot diagram $K$, we get a corresponding set $\mathrm{C}(K)$ of crossings of $K$. Also, to each subset $x$ of $\mathrm{C}(K)$, we can assign a natural number $f(x)$ by defining $f(x)$ to be the number of copies of the unknot we get when we take the overstrand left at every crossing that appears in $x$, and take it right for every crossing that doesn't appear in $x$. This is extremely vague, but if you know how to compute the [bracket polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_polynomial) you probably know what I mean. Please comment if my meaning is unclear. In summary, each knot diagram $K$ yields a set $\mathrm{C}(K)$ and a function $f : \mathcal{P}(\mathrm{C}(K)) \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is the powerset operator.

> **Question.** Does the pair $(\mathrm{C}(K),f)$ allow us to recover the knot diagram $K$?

Comment: I think another way to formulate this question, in case it's useful, is "can a knot diagram be recovered from just the chain groups for Khonanov homology?" (And Adam Lowrance gives a counterexample.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pair $(C(K),f)$ is not enough to recover the knot diagram $K$. [Mutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_(knot_theory)) on a knot diagram will preserve the function $f$, but not the knot diagram (or even the knot type).

As a specific example, consider the two-component links below.

[image]

The second of these links is obtained from the first by performing a mutation inside of the red circle. These two diagrams are different even up to planar isotopy because the first contains a component with no self-crossings and the second does not. It turns out that these are diagrams of the same link, but in the interest of keeping the number of crossings small, I chose this example.

The set $C(K)$ here is of size $2^6=64$. If my back of the envelope computations are correct, then the following chart displays the behavior of $f$ for both diagrams:
$$\begin{array}{c | c}
\#~\text{subsets of crossings} & \#~\text{components}\\
\hline
12 & 1\\
27 & 2\\
20 & 3\\
5 & 4
\end{array}.$$